# Implementation of for loop in tensorflow lazy execution mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a `for` loop into tensorflow lazy execution mode. I know that the equivalent for tensorflow is `tf.while_loop` but it seem cumbersome and I do not feel comfortable to use it. So, I was wondering if I could implemented using a for loop. The problem as I get it is that the `for` loop is actually being executed outside the graph (prior to this I guess) and it functions as if the last iteration was defined only. A simple example might be of some (clarification) help:

Eager mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
ref = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0, 2],
                   [0, 1, 2, 2],
                   [1, 2, 1, 3]], dtype=tf.int32)
true_array = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
false_array = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 1, 0]])
for j in range(3):
    samples = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(ref[j, :], axis=-1), 3), lambda: true_array, lambda: false_array)
    update = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, [[j]], samples)
print('Eager ref', ref.numpy())
```

which outputs the correct result (it changes the lines of `ref` having a sum of 3 to `true_array` while all other lines (which do not have 3) are set to `false_array`.

```
Eager ref [[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0]]
```

But in lazy mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ref = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0, 2],
                   [0, 1, 2, 2],
                   [1, 2, 1, 3]], dtype=tf.int32)
true_array = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
false_array = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 1, 0]])
for j in range(3):
    samples = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(ref[j, :], axis=0), 1), lambda: true_array, lambda: false_array)
    update = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, [[j]], samples)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # print(sess.run(ref))
    print('update', sess.run(update))
    print('samples', sess.run(samples))
```

the output is the same as if I were using `j = 2` (last iteration) only. Only the last line is being processed.

```
update [[0 1 0 2]
 [0 1 2 2]
 [1 0 1 0]]
samples [[1 0 1 0]]
```

Of course a even more cumbersome approach would be to split this loop into separate ops and call every one of them:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ref = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0, 2],
                   [0, 1, 2, 2],
                   [1, 2, 1, 3]], dtype=tf.int32)
true_array = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
false_array = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 1, 0]])
# test = tf.reduce_sum(ref[0, :], axis=-1)
samples0 = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(ref[0, :], axis=-1), 3), lambda: true_array, lambda: false_array)
update0 = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, [[0]], samples0)
samples1 = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(ref[1, :], axis=-1), 3), lambda: true_array, lambda: false_array)
update1 = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, [[1]], samples1)
samples2 = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(ref[2, :], axis=-1), 3), lambda: true_array, lambda: false_array)
update2 = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, [[2]], samples2)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # print('test', sess.run(test))
    print('update0', sess.run(update0))
    print('update1', sess.run(update1))
    print('update2', sess.run(update2))
    print('samples', sess.run(samples))
    print('ref', sess.run(ref))
```

with output:

```
update [[0 1 0 2]
 [0 1 2 2]
 [1 0 1 0]]
samples [[1 0 1 0]]
update0 [[1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 2 2]
 [1 2 1 3]]
update1 [[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 2 1 3]]
update2 [[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0]]
samples [[1 0 1 0]]
ref [[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0]]
```

So, my question is if it is possible to implement this `for` loop inside tensorflow or am I forced to use `tf.while_loop` only? Also, how could I implement it using `tf.while_loop` if that's unavoidable?