# Implementation of while_loop in tensorflow containing scatter_nd_update

Tags: python, tensorflow

OK this question is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64233698/implementation-of-for-loop-in-tensorflow-lazy-execution-mode) (and if it worked it could be considered an answer that question also). Anyway, I am trying to implement a `tf.while_loop` for my needs. I need to apply an `tf.scatter_nd_update` function in it but for some reason it throws an error.

A small script revealing the issue is this one:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ref = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0, 2],
                   [0, 1, 2, 2],
                   [1, 2, 1, 3]], dtype=tf.int32)
true_array = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
false_array = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 1, 0]])
num_iters = tf.Variable(3, dtype=tf.int32)  # 3


def body(ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters):
    samples = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(ref[j, :], axis=0), 1), lambda: true_array, lambda: false_array)
    ref = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, [[j]], samples)
     j = tf.add(j, 1)
    return ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters


cond = lambda ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters: tf.less(j, num_iters)
j = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32)  # tf.constant(0)
ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print('ref', sess.run(ref))
    print('j', sess.run(j))
```

which throws an error

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'

in line `ref = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, [[j]], samples)`. For some reason one of my objects is a `Tensor` which does not contain a `_lazy_read` attribute. A similar issue here proposes to convert a Tensor to Variable but in my case it does not work. I have tried to use `ref = lambda: tf.Variable(ref)` inside the `body` function but this throws another error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Does anyone knows how to implement this `while_loop` with `scatter_nd_update`?

It may worth noting that the above code works in eager mode just fine.

tf version 1.15

Edit:
removed the eager execution mode (being inserted by mistake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration and dead-end search I found a working solution for my combination.

I should only use [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update) in place of [`tf.scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) and it seems to work fine. I am not in a position to specify the differences between those two though. The first one states that:

> Scatter updates into an existing tensor according to indices.

while the second one:

> Applies sparse updates to individual values or slices in a Variable.

yet to me they seem to accomplish the same job. Anyway, maybe the tensorflow team had similar thoughts because of the two only the first one remains in tf 2.0 version I think.

```
import tensorflow as tf

ref = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0, 2],
                   [0, 1, 2, 2],
                   [1, 2, 1, 3]], dtype=tf.int32)
true_array = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
false_array = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 1, 0]])
num_iters = tf.Variable(3, dtype=tf.int32)  # 3


def body(ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters):
    samples = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(ref[j, :], axis=0), 1), lambda: true_array, lambda: false_array)
    ref = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(ref, [[j]], samples)
     j = tf.add(j, 1)
    return ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters


cond = lambda ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters: tf.less(j, num_iters)
j = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32)  # tf.constant(0)
ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [ref, true_array, false_array, j, num_iters])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print('ref', sess.run(ref))
    print('j', sess.run(j))
```

with output being:

```
update [[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0]]
samples 3
```

Comment: Late to the party, but in case it's helpful - tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update updates an existing tensor (passed as the first argument) with the updates, whereas tf.scatter_nd_update zero-initialised a new tensor and updates it with the updates. The documentation is a bit clearer now days!